# Add comments to an order

Tags: api, rest-api, magento2.3.1

So when I look online, it looks super simple... Even the swagger docs show it to be simple, but I've tried 2 different Magento sites now (different versions) and the API simply doesn't work...

Order ID:1 (first ever order)

Magento Version 2.3.1

POST TO: `index.php/rest/V1/orders/2/comments`

Content:

```
{
  "statusHistory": {
    "comment": "TEST ORDER COMMENT",
    "entity_id": 1,
    "entity_name": "string",
    "is_customer_notified": 0,
    "is_visible_on_front": 0,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "status": "Waiting_on_Supplier",
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}
```

All I seem to get back is the content... I can even see my custom comments I added - but it's not giving back a boolean as per the docs...

Here is the response I'm getting back:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "comment": "test",
            "created_at": "2019-08-15 18:16:27",
            "entity_id": 1,
            "entity_name": "order",
            "is_customer_notified": 0,
            "is_visible_on_front": 0,
            "parent_id": 1,
            "status": "processing"
        },
        {
            "comment": "tes2",
            "created_at": "2019-08-15 18:49:03",
            "entity_id": 2,
            "entity_name": "order",
            "is_customer_notified": 0,
            "is_visible_on_front": 0,
            "parent_id": 1,
            "status": "processing"
        }
    ],
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "parent_id",
                        "value": "1",
                        "condition_type": "eq"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "total_count": 2
}
```

Hope someone can shed a bit of light! I'm very confused.

Comment: I think it should be posted to this URL:
POST TO: index.php/rest/V1/orders/1/comments

Not this one:
POST TO: index.php/rest/V1/orders/2/comments

Comment: Sorry that was me testing on order id 1 and 2 and not updating my output here.

So its not that, i just can't seem to see it working...

I post to the first order /1 not /2 but regardless, neither work!